# Locked package namespace

Tags: r, namespaces, package

I am using the "BMA" package in R 3.1.0, and get an error when running one of the functions in the package, `iBMA.glm`. When running the example in the package documentation:

```
## Not run:
############ iBMA.glm
library("MASS")
library("BMA")
data(birthwt)
y<- birthwt$lo
x<- data.frame(birthwt[,-1])
x$race<- as.factor(x$race)
x$ht<- (x$ht>=1)+0
x<- x[,-9]
x$smoke <- as.factor(x$smoke)
x$ptl<- as.factor(x$ptl)
x$ht <- as.factor(x$ht)
x$ui <- as.factor(x$ui)
### add 41 columns of noise
noise<- matrix(rnorm(41*nrow(x)), ncol=41)
colnames(noise)<- paste('noise', 1:41, sep='')
x<- cbind(x, noise)
iBMA.glm.out<- iBMA.glm( x, y, glm.family="binomial",
factor.type=FALSE, verbose = TRUE,
thresProbne0 = 5 )
summary(iBMA.glm.out)
```

I get the error:

```
Error in registerNames(names, package, ".__global__", add) : 
  The namespace for package "BMA" is locked; no changes in the global variables list may be made.
```

I get the error in RStudio running R 3.1.0 on Ubuntu.

on Windows 7, from RStudio and the R console I get a similar error:

```
Error in utils::globalVariables(c("nastyHack_glm.family", "nastyHack_x.df")) : 
  The namespace for package "BMA" is locked; no changes in the global variables list may be made.
```

I also get the same error when running my own data in the function. I'm not clear on what this error means and how to work around the error to be actually able to use the function. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: I was just able to replicate this error. My advice would be emailing the maintainer of the package